# How Can I Safely Remove WP-Super Cache without messing my site up?

Tags: plugins, cache

So apparently some people cannot view my site because they said it only loads the sidebar. This only happens to some people and it only started happening after I installed the w3 super cache. I've read about people's website getting messed up after removing it. What's the best way to safely remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Besides deactivating and deleting the Plugin, you have to check a few files and folders to be sure everything works.

### [Perform a full backup](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups)

This should go without saying, save all the data you get for eventual troubleshooting.

#### wp-config.php

Check for the constants `WPCACHEHOME` and `WP_CACHE`, and delete/comment them out. Remember where your `WPCACHEHOME` was located.

#### Cache-Folder

Delete the folder specified in `WPCACHEHOME`, using your CPanel or a FTP connection.

Usually this folder is located in `wp-content/cache`.

#### Configuration Files

Check your `wp-content` folder for files like `wp-cache-config.php`, and rename/delete them.

#### Test your site

Thoroughly test if everything works as expected.

### Plan B

Create a Mirror WordPress installation, and install everything besides the caching plugin. This may be a bit more work, but you do not have to worry about leftovers and broken connections.